# How to plot bar chart to compare multiple systems with multiple variables using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, data-analysis

I'm doing some basic data analysis with Pandas and am having trouble with plotting data. I have data for multiple systems where each system has rank positions (1-10). Within each rank position there are grades A, C, and F, with a percentage. I'd like to have a graph for each system, where the x-axis contains the ranks and the y-axis contains the grade percentages. Here is an example of my data:

```
{
  "System1": {
      "1": {
             "A": 0.5,
             "C": 0.3,
             "F": 0.1
           },
      "2": {
             "A": 0.3,
             "C": 0.3,
             "F": 0.4
           },
      ...,
      "10": {
              "A": 0.1,
              "C": 0.3,
              "F": 0.6
            }
   },
   "System2": {
       "1": {
              ...
            },
       ...,
       "10": {
              ...
        }
   }
}
```

I would like to produce a graph that looks like this:
[image]

I have loaded my data into a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ranked_grades)` but I'm having trouble with getting Pandas to work with my data's nested structure. My dataframe looks like this once loaded:

```
                                              System1                                           System2                                
1   {'C': 0.35377358490566035, 'F': 0.132075471698...  {'C': 0.3696682464454976, 'F': 0.1611374407582...  
2   {'C': 0.33490566037735847, 'F': 0.372641509433...  {'C': 0.3459715639810427, 'F': 0.2890995260663...  
3   {'C': 0.330188679245283, 'F': 0.41037735849056...  {'C': 0.3080568720379147, 'F': 0.4502369668246...  
4   {'C': 0.2783018867924528, 'F': 0.5235849056603...  {'C': 0.3175355450236967, 'F': 0.4739336492890... 
...
10  {'C': 0.2830188679245283, 'F': 0.5943396226415...  {'C': 0.24170616113744076, 'F': 0.630331753554...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm learning a ton of stuff here.  I may update this answer if I find more.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = {
    k0: {
        k1: {
            k2: np.random.randint(0, 10) / 10 for k2 in list('ACF')
        } for k1 in range(1, 11)
    } for k0 in ['System1', 'System2']
}

df = pd.Panel(d).to_frame().rename_axis([None, None]).T.stack()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(6, 4), sharex=True)
for i, (name, group) in enumerate(df.groupby(level=0)):
    group.xs(name).sort_index().plot.bar(ax=axes[i], ylim=[0, 1])
    axes[i].set_title(name, rotation=270, position=(1.05, .55),
                      backgroundcolor='gray')

axes[0].legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, .2), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
axes[1].legend().remove()

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.1)
```

[image]

Comment: That was a tough one.Thanks for your help! I'd be happy to see any other techniques you come up with for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

The from_dict method is not expecting nested dicts. So you'll need to loop through and read the data in that way.

```
dfs = []
for key in sorted(ranked_grades):
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ranked_grades[key]))
```

Then, shove them together with concat

```
data = pd.concat(dfs, keys=sorted(ranked_grades))
```

Now you should have a data structure you can work with.